# Pass arguments to mongo script

Tags: mongodb, sh

I am executing a mongo script in command line with following command.

mongo --quiet --eval remove_audits.js

I want to pass arguments to mongo script like below.

mongo --quiet --eval remove_audits.js arg1 arg2

Let me know how can I do this for mongo script.

Comment: Any one has solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

(repost from [MongoDB User email](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/iLA6ekJHLu4))

There's no way to get the arguments to look exactly like that, but what you can do is use `--eval` to pass arguments to your scripts.

Ex:
`mongo --quiet --eval 'let arg1="foo", arg2="bar";' remove_audits.js`

You can also take a look at [this script](https://github.com/Machyne/scriptsnstuff/blob/master/workload.js) that I wrote to see an example of how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small utility to solve the problem for myself. With the `mongoexec` utility, you would be able to run the command `./remove_audits.js arg1 arg2` by adding the following to the beginning of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/mongoexec --quiet
```

Within the script, you can then access the arguments as `args[0]` and `args[1]`.

https://github.com/pveierland/mongoexec